# C# - Windows Forms - Windows 7 - Overlay another application's window

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that needs to overlay another application's window.  As the overlayed moves I need my application to move along with it.

I am using the following code to get the window and position my window over it.

```
public static void DockToWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndParent)
    {
        RECT rectParent = new RECT();
        GetWindowRect(hwndParent, ref rectParent);

        RECT clientRect = new RECT();
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, ref clientRect);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, hwndParent, rectParent.Left, 
                                     (rectParent.Bottom - (clientRect.Bottom - 
                                      clientRect.Top)),  // Left position
                                     (rectParent.Right - rectParent.Left),
                                     (clientRect.Bottom - clientRect.Top),
                                     SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOZORDER);

     }
```

I also set the form.TopMost to true.
The problem I am having is that the overlay takes focus away from the overlayed window.
I just want my overlay to sit on top of this window but not steal focus.  If the user clicks on the overlayed window I want it to work as it did before I placed the overlay.
However, if the user clicks on the overlay I need to capture the mouse on the overlay.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In winforms, you can avoid focus-setting by overriding ShowWithoutActivation

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
{
  get { return true; }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showwithoutactivation.aspx

Comment: I tried this and it does work, but it was still stealing focus when I moved the overlayed window.  I have a solution.

Comment: @JimBucciferro Great! You should post your fix as a self-answer for others to read later, and also edit your question to include the requirement for no-focus also when moving.

Comment: My solution works but it keeps my overlay on top of all windows instead of just the window I want to overlay.

Answer (score 0):

From [Floating Controls, Tooltip-style](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Controls/Popup_Windows/Floating_Controls/article.asp), try this on your overlay form:

```
private const int WM_NCHITTEST             = 0x0084;
private const int HTTRANSPARENT            = (-1);

/// <summary>
/// Overrides the standard Window Procedure to ensure the
/// window is transparent to all mouse events.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="m">Windows message to process.</param>
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
  if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
  {
    m.Result = (IntPtr) HTTRANSPARENT;
  }
  else
  {
    base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this issue by updating the SetWindowPos code to use the overlay form's Left,Top,Right, and Bottom properties instead of using GetWindowRect.

```
 RECT rect = new RECT();
 GetWindowRect(hostWindow, ref rect);
 SetWindowPos(this.Handle, NativeWindows.HWND_TOPMOST,
                                         rect.Left+10,
                                         rect.Bottom - (Bottom - Top),
                                        (rect.Right - rect.Left),
                                         Bottom - Top,
                                         0);
```

This code aligns the overlay window along the bottom edge of the host window.
The problem I have now is that my overlay is on top of all windows, not just the window I want to overlay.  I've tried HWND_TOP which does the same thing, and the overlayed window handle, which places my overlay beneath the window.

Any ideas - do I need to use SetParent() ?

Comment: I thought the question was about clicking on the overlay form taking the focus away.

Comment: It is.  With the previous code it would take away focus.  The new code fixes that but now shows above all windows and I only want it to show above a selected window.